# JSON reader to extract records as Java strings, without parsing

Tags: java, json, reader

Is there any `JSON` library (reader) that can do string extraction, "pull" style (record by record), from a data source (e.g., `InputStream`), without fully parsing the input into an object?

For example, consider a file with the following 3 `JSON` records in a single line:

```
{"a":"b"}{"c":"d"}{"e":"f"}
```

These could be spread in 3 lines and also `JSON` can have multiline records like

```
{
  "a":"b"
}
```

What is needed is a JSON string "reader" that can iterate over all input (similarly to an `Iterator<String>` object), record-by-record, on demand (i.e. like [StAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX), not [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML)). For example, in the above case with the 3 records, the output would successively be

```
reader.next() --> {"a":"b"}
reader.next() --> {"c":"d"}
reader.next() --> {"e":"f"}
```

A technique would be to use a library that parses records in objects (e.g., like the `JsonNode` object in [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)) and then retrieve the string version from the extracted object, but for reading only this has the unnecessary overhead of parsing.

Comment: It's not mainly about where to stop and start - all parsers do that. It's about reading each record as a string and nothing else. :-)

Comment: Why?  You need the bulk of the parsing anyway, to tell when you're at the end of the current payload.

Comment: (Or you can simply split at `}{`, if you're sure the data will always conform to that structure.)

Comment: You cannot assume that there will be a "}{" string in the first place. Events can come one per line, or across multiple lines each.

Comment: Have you looked at this document: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html? If you think this would be helpful and would like me to post up some sample code to answer your example, feel free to let me know. I have used this in the past but only for small data streams coming in.

Comment: The examples in the document use streaming, which means one has to keep track of the internal token names of the JSON library and create the record string manually, depending on the sequence of these tokens. What I need is a string iterator over all the JSON records in a document. If JSON did not have escaped characters and many other special cases, it would be easy to implement the iterator by just matching opening and closing curly braces, but in reality it is not that simple. Thanks for the reference and +1.

Comment: There's a project on Github that might be useful for you: https://github.com/beckchr/staxon According to the documentation, it should allow you to read JSON using the Java Streaming API for XML (also known as STAX). You can use Maven to get the library or download it manually through the github page as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have used that library in the past. It's useful, but not for the use case described in the question. Thanks again for the reference and +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Jackson can be used to solve exactly this problem this using JsonParser.

For example, with myfile.txt with the following:

```
{"a":"b"}
{
  "c":"d"
}{"e":"f"}
```

The following program will output:

```
{"a":"b"}
{"c":"d"}
{"e":"f"}
```

Code:

```
public class Reader implements Closeable {
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
    JsonParser jp;
    public Reader(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        jp = jsonFactory.createParser(inputStream);
        jp.nextToken();
    }
    public String next() throws IOException {
        while (jp.currentToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT){
            jp.nextToken();
        }
        jp.nextToken(); //Next token will be the key
        if (jp.currentToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("{\"")
                .append(jp.getCurrentName())
                .append("\":\"");
            jp.nextToken();//Next token will be the value. 
            sb.append(jp.getValueAsString())
                .append("\"}");
            return sb.toString();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void close() throws IOException {
        jp.close();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Reader reader = new Reader(new FileInputStream("myfile.txt"));
        while (true){
            String token = reader.next();
            if (token == null){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(token);
        }
    }
}
```

Dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```